# SQL Server Management Studio network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I get the following error when trying to connect to the default database on my computer: http://s7.postimage.org/dk5abnu15/sql_error.jpg

The underlined part means "The system can't find the file specified". But I don't have any idea what it means. I have installed SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate if that matters. I use Windows authentication and for Server name I type `.` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` (both don't work).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go in Adminstrative tools --> Services ---> There you will find SQL SERVER and you need to start that this happened when your service stop from any reason.

Comment: I found there "SQL Server VSS Writer" and it was started. No other services' names started with SQL.

Comment: means you missed to check when you start to install Sql Server you need to install it again and when start installing you need to check SQL Server Management studio .

Comment: These all will you can see in services SQL SEVER, SQL SERVER AGENT, SQL SERVer Analysis, SQL Server Browser, SQL SERVER Integration service, SQL SERVER Reporting service, Sql server VSS Writer ..